# Database table not created after running plugin:refresh

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, octobercms

I'm following [this tutorial](https://vimeo.com/104896353) to create a simple OctoberCMS plugin. So I execute the following commands in order:

```
php artisan create:plugin Acme.Demo  
php artisan create:model Acme.Demo Task  
php artisan plugin:refresh Acme.Demo
```

ouput:

```
Rolled back: Acme.Demo  
Reinstalling plugin...  
Acme.Demo  
 - v1.0.1:  First version of Demo  
 - v1.0.2:  Create the TODO Tasks table
```

Here is the content of `create_task_table.php` in the updates folder:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Demo\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('acme_demo_tasks', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('acme_demo_tasks');
    }

}
```

According to the tutorial, after this step I should be able to see the `acme_demo_tasks` table in the database, but I fail to see it there and it seems that the table has not been created. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `create_task_table.php` in your updates folder?

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo, the name of file is `create_tasks_table.php`. Be sure the name of file is correct. And in your `version.yaml` call this file (4:07 in tutorial video).

Comment: @JánKyselica Thank you. The problem was that I had written "- create_task_table.php" in the version.yaml file, and after changing it to "- create_tasks_table.php" the problem was fixed. I didn't note that the comments in the yaml file are so important and are used that way. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the name of database migration file in your `version.yaml`, it should be `create_tasks_table.php`.